# MyEclipse Deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, myeclipse

Are other people using the MyEclipse Libraries? Every time I start working in a project and then update MyEclipse the build libraries change or versions are not what I need. Is it common practice to put up with it or do people use an external set of libraries and only rely on MyEclipse's when they develop a quick project?

Also, how do people handle the issue of creating WAR files with certain libraries attached? When I create the WAR it dump all my libraries into it like my test ones and I don't want those in my web application. I've tried configuring my deployment under --> Preferences -> MyEclipse -> Web -> Deployment.

Comment: Use a proper build tool to make your war instead. MyEclipse should support maven at least.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. If you answer the question with you comment I will make it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proper build tool to make your war instead. MyEclipse should support maven at least.